# Need to change featured slider image size in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

i need to change the size of featured images on my [aviation classifieds](http://www.flightravelgear.com) website. I am a pilot and i dont know coding stuff. I saw other threads on stackoverflow and I tried to go to media settings in wordpress backend but that did not change the size of images on the featured slider.

Can somebody tell me exactly how can i do it programmatically. Which file and what type of code should i use.

Comment: Where is the featured slider on the website?
Could you please give a link to the page having the featured image slider?

Comment: If you see on home page below the menu this slider appears with next and last buttons. Since the featured ads are less so the slider might not show up. but i want to change the size of the thumbnails or so that appears there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Login using http://www.flightravelgear.com/wp-admin

Then go to `Appearance` and then to the `theme editor`

After that you will see file named as `style.css`.Find `image_class` over there and add `width` and `height` to that.

```
.image_class {
width: 100px; //give your image width
height: 80px; //give your image height
}
```

Add

```
.featured-three {
left: 10px;
}
```

Answer for latest question

Add another this line of code below `image _class`

```
#slider{
height:210px !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect that worked but check my site, now the featured label is misaligned and also the slider box should be little bigger. how can i change the slider style? Also the default thmnail is now stretched and skewed!

Comment: thanks i am checking, i voted but it says i need some reputation? Thanks

Comment: I am not getting ..What you wish to do ??

Comment: now that the size of image is increased, it displays as a blurred image. Also due the text that is cutting out, i need to increase the length of slider. I changed it but the the previous and next buttons remained on there place instead of moving at the bottom.